# door frame 1 inch smaller on each side of door opening

Tags: repair, doors

[image: front door inside cap]I had a custom wood door installed, but the door frame of this door was made 1 inch two small on each side of the door opening. The contractor used some wood screws to keep the door frame aligned with the door opening. Now in between the cap of the frame and the door opening they used foam so seal the gaps in the inch difference .

After the wood trim was installed around the door frame, there are now gaps between the trim and sheet rock, inside, and outside I have 1/4" gap around the door opening, a stucco trim that is around wood door, placed on top of brick. Also the wood door is an arch door and I have a big gap between the trim and sheet rock, see pic .

How do I correct this gap? Or does the door maker need to redo the door frame? He claims it was the guy you made my house fault, I need help with how to fix this problem

Comment: They need to make a wider trim to cover the gap. These guys must be real jokers as the trim should not have been put on once they saw it was two narrow. Doors and windows are normally smaller than the opening so it can be put in plumb.

Comment: Did they fit a 30" frame into an opening made for a 32" frame or something like that?

Comment: My question is how to fix this problem ? Whatever I need to do to fix this, even if it is to Redo frame again

Comment: It's the general contractor's responsibility to handle this sort of thing. That's what you pay them for. You contracted to have a certain product built, and what you describe doesn't meet that description.

Answer (score 1):

Normally,the frame of a prehung door is a bit smaller than the opening.

When it is installed, that space allows you to use shims to fine-tune the frame's poisition so it is straight and level snd square even if the opening isn't. Mounting screws are then driven through the shims and into the structural framing to hold the door in that position.

Gaps around the shims are filled with insulation, and trim boards attached inside and outside cover that gap.

From your description I agree with @edbeal and @brhams that either they ordered a door that is entirely too small for the space, or they are trying to use unreasonably narrow trim, or both. The trim around my doors is a full 3" wide; that could cover many mistakes.

Comment: Hello how small can the door frame be? I was told  1 inch is way to be be in door opening

Comment: Depends on how many 2x4s you are willing to install as cripple studs to help fill the space, and how wide your trim is our how much you're willing to rework the wall surface on both sides... 1" (giving you a half inch to play with on each side) is probably close to optimal, and it's what I'd expect a pro to order...